# How to align the height of a custom detent with the content of a presented UISheetPresentationController in UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, mobile, uikit, uisheetpresentationcontroller

I am currently using the [`UISheetPresentationController`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisheetpresentationcontroller) in UIKit to show a sheet on top of a `UIViewController` to give additional information about the underlying `UIViewController`. The sheet will not block the interaction or dim the underlying `UIViewController`. The presented `UISheetPresentationController` will have a `UICollectionView` with multiple sections to display the additional information.

I would like to have a similar implementation like Apple Maps where the height of the smallest detent is aligned with the actual content of the presented sheet:
[Apple Maps Sheet displaying exactly the search bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14jVM.jpg)

The smaller custom detent should have the same height than the first section of the `UICollectionView` in the presented sheet. Since the underlying view is a different `UIViewController` than the presented sheet it is difficult to create a custom detent that is exactly the same height as the content of the first section and would respond to any dynamic view changes.

The simplest solution that I came up with is to use a constant value for the detent height (e.g. 100) and then also use this constant value as a height restriction of the first section in the `UICollectionView` in the presented sheet. But using constant height variables could introduce issues when using a different font size and could therefore break the content of the first section of the `UICollectionView`. I would be interested if there is a better approach than manually aligning the heights of the sheet detent and the content of the sheet or if there are any best practices to achieve a similar behaviour like in Apple Maps.

Comment: Hello Philipp, I was just about to search a solution for the exact same problem. I also want my size to be dynamic, as my content depending on font sizes may change. How did you solve your problem? Would be awesome to hear! Cheers

Comment: Hi Gerog, unfortunately I did not yet find a better solution than the one described above. I will post it here once I found something better.